# Prove using combinatorics $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{\lfloor{\frac{n-k}{2}}\rfloor}=\binom{2n+1}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics

Prove using combinatorics

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{\lfloor{\frac{n-k}{2}}\rfloor}=\binom{2n+1}{n}$$

The right side seems easy for the right side we have floor function it seems we have to count the number of subsets that $A_i \notin A_j$ but when I try to prove I can't show the right side.Any hints?

Comment: This [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087559/) has two algebraic proofs and one combinatorial one.

Comment: This problem is also https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h48585 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a combinatorially based approach.

> **RHS:** The right hand side $$\binom{2n+1}{n}$$ is the number of $n$-element subsets of a set with $2n+1$ elements.
>
> **LHS:** We partition the $2n+1$ elements in $n$ pairs and one singleton and count the number of ways to select $n$ elements from the total of $2n+1$ elements by classifying the pairs in two categories.
>
> - pairs from which we take one element only
> - pairs from which we take both elements
>
> Let $0\leq k\leq n$. If we select $k$ pairs from which take one element only, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ different possibilities to do so and since for each pair of this category there are two choices to select an element, we get
>   \begin{align*}
> 2^k\binom{n}{k}
> \end{align*}
>   different possibilities to select $k$ elements from pairs of the first category.
>
> We now have to select $n-k$ elements from pairs of the second category and according to the classification of this category, we have to choose *both* elements of each pair. So, we have $\lfloor (n-k)/2\rfloor$ pairs of this category to select which can be done in
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{n-k}{\lfloor (n-k)/2\rfloor}
> \end{align*}
>   ways. Observe that if $n-k$ is even, we won't take the singleton and if $n-k$ is odd we have to take the singleton in order to get $n$ elements.

*Note:* This proof is a special case of *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087559/a-combinatorial-identity-with-binomial-coefficients-and-floor-function/2089099#2089099)*.

Comment: What a about a combinatorial proof?

Comment: @TahaAkbari: Proof transformed into a combinatorial one.